# how to invoke EndInvoke in async method

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, asynchronous

I have a normal method

```
public List<string> FindNearByCity(string targetCity)
{
// ... some implementation
}
```

I want to add async support for this method, so i wrote this:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginFindNearByCity(string targetCity, AsyncCallback callback, object obj)
{
    Func<string, List<string>> method = FindNearByCity;
    return method.BeginInvoke(targetCity, callback, obj);
}

public List<string> EndFindNearByCity(IAsyncResult  result)
{
    Func<string, List<string>> method = FindNearByCity;
    return method.EndInvoke(result);
}
```

The BeginFindNearByCity works fine, however when it comes to EndFindNearByCity, exception will throw when it hit EndInvoke.

I look into the auto gen Async web service method, seems i need to implement something call "ChannelBase"

can anyone point me to something that more simple like tutorial or sample that i can have a look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate you are creating in your `EndXXX` method is a separate instance to the delegate you create in your `BeginXXX` method, therefore it has no knowledge of the `IAsyncResult` which you are passing to its `EndInvoke()` method.

You have to use the same delegate in the `EndXXX` method as the `BeginXXX` method, e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly Func<string, List<string>> method;

    public Foo()
    {
        this.method = this.FindNearByCity;
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginFindNearByCity(string targetCity, AsyncCallback callback, object obj)
    {
        return this.method.BeginInvoke(targetCity, callback, obj);
    }

    public List<string> EndFindNearByCity(IAsyncResult  result)
    {
        return this.method.EndInvoke(result);
    }

    public List<string> FindNearByCity(string targetCity)
    {
        // ... some implementation
    }
}
```